# class probability column for yardstick::roc_cruve

Tags: r, tidymodels, yardstick

I have a doubt regarding the column to pass when calling roc_curve. If you look at the example provided at https://www.tidymodels.org/start/recipes/#predict-workflow you can see that the argument provided is .pred_late.

```
flights_pred %>% 
  roc_curve(truth = arr_delay, .pred_late) %>% 
  autoplot()
```

Why it is used instead of .pred_on_time?

For me the value `.pred_on_time > 0.5` ==> `on_time`. I know the relation `.pred_on_time+.pred_late=1`, but it is more natural to write:

```
flights_pred %>% 
  roc_curve(truth = arr_delay, .pred_on_time) %>% 
  autoplot()
```

Comment: Asking for explanation of tutorials is not really on topic here. Perhaps you ask for migration to the Data Science forum https://datascience.stackexchange.com/, or better just delete and repost there?

Comment: You can use the [`event_level` argument to specify](https://yardstick.tidymodels.org/reference/roc_curve.html) which level of the factor you want to use as the event and change this if you want.